# finish parameter in angular 2 didn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, subscription

I use subscribe to perform lines of codes after getting the result from API. Here are my codes

```
this.attRecService.getAgendaData(moment(this.viewDate).format('YYYY-MM')).subscribe(
        resp => {
            this.agendaData = resp;

            for (let item of resp) {
                if (item.schedule) {
                    for (let sched of item.schedule) {
                        this.events.push({
                            'start': new Date(moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
                            'title': sched.title 
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        () => {
            console.log('display');
            this.displayClockDetail();
        }
    );
```

But in the part where I tried to console log the word ***display***, it seems like it won' t get into that parameter. What is wrong?

Comment: You are missing error block

Comment: Thank you. I got it already @mxr7350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
() => {
    console.log('display');
    this.displayClockDetail();
}
```

will work only if the request is failed (some errors happen) and is not correctly handled before it.

If you want a function to work when the observable is completed, you can pass as the third parameter to the `subscribe` function.

```
.subscibe(() => { ok }, () => { error }, () => { completed })
```

Comment: So you mean that part is still the error handling and I should do it in the third parameter?

Comment: Yes I mean that.

Comment: Also if you do an http request, observable will be completed automatically, but if you use custom written observable, you need to complete it explicitly to let the third function work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, after check in console what message displayed

```
 this.attRecService.getAgendaData(moment(this.viewDate).format('YYYY-MM'))
 .subscribe((res: any) => {
     if(res) {
       for (let item of resp) {
            if (item.schedule) {
                for (let sched of item.schedule) {
                    this.events.push({
                        'start': new Date(moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
                        'title': sched.title 
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        console.log('display');
      }
 }, (error?: any) => {
     console.log('error');
});
```